# Tooltip still showing for "comments disabled" text on deleted/locked posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, tooltips, locked-questions

Recently when we can't post new comment, text describing it was added which is good and dandy.

However, the tooltip is still there lurking in the darkness awaiting mouse hover:

> [image]

Can it please be removed?

Comment: Do you want the tooltip removed altogether, or do you want it to say something different?

Comment: @Cody tried to think of proper tooltip but couldn't think of any; the text is pretty clear as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now. Shadow Wizard, your long wait is over.

Comment: Even in the 6-8 (years) range. Kudos! :D