# "Comments disabled" should not be a link

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

I have found a design bug. If comments are locked on a question, the "add comment" link is still a link, although it is not clickable and serves no purpose as a link. See for example here [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

[image]

Hovering over the element still produces the link mouse pointer and the link changes its color.

This is related to [Tooltip still showing for "comments disabled" text on deleted/locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190753/tooltip-still-showing-for-comments-disabled-text-on-deleted-locked-posts). I would suggest to disable the link behavior and use a different tooltip.

Comment: Yup, it should be just text.

Comment: Another example would be the [Sandbox Archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/296077/sandbox-archive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed. The `Comments disabled` text is no longer a link.

Comment: AFter five years I really didn't think that would ever get fixed :). Thanks!