# Clicking "comments disabled" shows the UI to post a comment, but you actually can't

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Related: ["Comments disabled" should not be a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240578/350567)

[image: asdfghjkl]

Find a deleted post **with enough comments to have "show X more comments" appearing**, and click the "link". You'll see this box. Enter some random stuff and hit Enter, then you'll be told you can't post comments on a deleted post (unless you're a diamond moderator).

Comment: No repro. What browser? Extensions?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Google Chrome 64. with SEAutoReviewComments.

Comment: Try to disable this extension and see if this bug still happens.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Disabled all extensions. Still persists.

Comment: And different browser?

Comment: I managed to reproduce it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305643/349538) (10k link) in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. It seems like it only happens when there are enough comments for there to be a "show x more comments" link, otherwise it works as it should.

Comment: @DonaldDuck true, question should be edited then. (too busy ATM.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Question edited. Thanks Donald Duck.