# What's a frozen post?

Tags: support, terminology

When trying to add a comment to a deleted post (supposing I've managed to make the comment box and the "add comment" button appear, see [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306899/349538)), I get the following error message (emphasis mine):

> Cannot add comments to this post; it may be locked, deleted, or ***frozen***

I know what [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/349538) and [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/349538) posts are, but I've never heard of frozen posts.

After some search, I've found that chat rooms can be frozen, but this error message mentions frozen *posts*. All I could find about frozen posts was [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36970/349538) suggesting that "locked" posts be renamed to "frozen" posts, but that was never implemented (according to [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38673/349538), it's tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because the problem it was trying to solve was solved in another way).

So I'm still wondering what a frozen post is. Do "frozen" posts (using that terminology) even exist on Stack Exchange? If so, what are they? If not, why does the error message mention them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Frozen is an alternative term for a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

> In addition to the post notice being prominently displayed, posts which are historically locked are "frozen in time"...

Other types of [locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) behave somewhat differently from historical locks, which is why they are documented separately.

The (unlocked) answers of locked questions can receive fully-privileged edits even though the question itself cannot be edited by non-moderators. Frozen or historically-locked questions, however, cannot have their answers edited by non-moderators at all.

Comment: Like the the Android app is _frozen_ but is kept because it has historical significance, in other words, kept for old times sake!  : P